# Python / Pandas - How can I group a DF by two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataset that is built ike this:

```
hour weekday
12   2
14   1
12   2
```

and so on.
I want to display in a heatmap per weekday when the dataframe had most action (which is the sum of all events that happened on that weekday during that hour)

I tried wo work with groupBy

```
hm = df.groupby(['hour']).sum()
```

which shows me all events for the hours, but does not split the events across the weekdays

How can I keep the list so I have the weekdays as an x-axis and on the y-axis the sum of the hours on that weekday?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide example of input data and expected output of code. Thx

Comment: It seems like you want to group by the weekday instead of the hour like this: df.groupby(['weekday']).sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you expect is unclear, but I imagine you could be looking for [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
# computing crosstab
hm = pd.crosstab(df['hour'], df['weekday'])

# plotting heatmap
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(hm, cmap='Greys')
```

output:

```
weekday  1  2
hour         
12       0  2
14       1  0
```

[image]